# Thread not resuming in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, synchronization

I am using a thread to draw images onto a JFrame.
I added a keyListener to listen for the key **P**, when it is pressed, the drawing of images stops and when I press **P** again, the drawing should resume.

I tried using wait/ notify along with synchronized block for implementing this.
However only Pausing works, the resume never works.
Strange...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    static JFrame window1 = new JFrame();
    static boolean isPaused=false;
    Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
         public void run()
         {
             while(true)
             {
                 window1.paintImage();//fn to redraw an image
             }
         }
    };

    final Thread t = new Thread(r);

    window1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
    {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_P)
            {
                if(isPaused==false)
                {
                    synchronized(t)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            t.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1)
                        {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    isPaused=true;
                } else
                {
                    t.notifyAll();
                    isPaused=false;
                }
            }
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0){}
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0){}

    });


    t.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go through the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) of `Object.wait`.
When `t.wait()` is executed, the **current** thread is "paused", not `t`.
More exactly, you are pausing the SWING Thread that is in charge of handling inputs, not the `Thread t` that you created to redraw the image.
`t.wait()` makes the SWING Thread to wait until it receive a `notify()` which will never come because the `t.notifyAll()` can only be reached by this same SWING Thread (so it is like you are going to sleep and you are waiting for yourself to wake you up... good luck with that).

Here is one solution to fix it (not the best though, since it does not care about synchronization):

```
  final  boolean [] pause = new boolean []{false};
  Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
     public void run()
     {
         while(true)
         {
             if(!pause[0])
             window1.paintImage();//fn to redraw an image
         }
     }
};

...

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_P)
        {
            if(!pause[0])
            {
                pause[0] = true;
            } else
            {
                pause[0] = false;
            }
        }
    }
```